# magento 1.9.x 'position' column

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to understand what is the aim of the 'position' column of the table 'catalog_category_product':

```
      +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
      | Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
      +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
      | category_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
      | product_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
      **| position    | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |**
      +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

the table catalog_category_entity:

```
      | Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default |
      +----------------------+------+-----+---------+---+
      | entity_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | | 
      |entity_type_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                
      | attribute_set_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                
      | parent_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |                
      | created_at       | timestamp            | YES  |     | NULL    |                
      | updated_at       | timestamp            | YES  |     | NULL    |                
      | path             | varchar(255)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
      **| position         | int(11)              | NO   |     | NULL    |**                
      | level            | int(11)              | NO   | MUL | 0       |                
      | children_count   | int(11)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                
      +----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there are two types of positioning in the categories, one belongs to the position of the categories against each other, and one for the assigned products to show them in particular order, and that's what I believe the purpose of having position column.

I hope I answered your question.